# Cost of deploying a set of contracts

Tags: gas, openzeppelin

I've just started playing with solidity and Ethereum. I have a local ganache blockchain and I've deployed a small set of contracts based on openzeppelin (three .sol files).

The estimated cost of the deployment is 0.07582022 ETH.

I supposed that with a complete project the cost will be much higher.

Does the cost depend on the number of files or instructions? Does this high price depend on the use of openzeppelin?

Answer (score 2):

The price of deployment depends on the size of the contracts (bytecode payload).

Because each byte in the blockchain is preserved forever, the storage cost is premium.

Answer (score 2):

Deployment cost depends on the complexity of the contract constructor function and the contract size.

You can find more on [here](https://hackernoon.com/costs-of-a-real-world-ethereum-contract-2033511b3214) and [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. It is better to include in the answer the main points and only use the link to expand the details.